# Terraform simplify same attributes to multiple blocks

Tags: terraform

What would be a best-practice to pass the same attributes/parameters to multiple blocks?
I find myself always duplicating code because of this:

```json
  env              = var.env
  location         = var.location
  tags             = local.tags
  rg_name          = var.rg_name
  subscription_id  = var.subscription_id
  service_plan_id  = local.service_plan_id
  nodejs_version   = var.nodejs_version
```

Here is a sample of what I currently use:

```json
// development front-end NUXT APP dev
module "nuxt-app" {
  source = "./nuxt-app"

  env              = var.env
  name             = "appweb-${var.env}-001"
  app_service_name = "appweb-${var.env}-001"
  location         = var.location
  tags             = local.tags
  rg_name          = var.rg_name
  subscription_id  = var.subscription_id
  service_plan_id  = local.service_plan_id
  nodejs_version   = var.nodejs_version
}

module "nuxt-app-slot" {
  source = "./nuxt-app-slot"

  //skip this resource for non-dev environments
  count = local.prod_only

  env              = var.env
  name             = "preview"
  app_service_name = "appweb-${var.env}-001"
  location         = var.location
  tags             = local.tags
  rg_name          = var.rg_name
  subscription_id  = var.subscription_id
  service_plan_id  = local.service_plan_id
  nodejs_version   = var.nodejs_version
}
```

My target would be:

```json
// development front-end NUXT APP dev
module "nuxt-app" {
  source = "./nuxt-app"

  name             = "appweb-${var.env}-001"
  app_service_name = "appweb-${var.env}-001"

  ...add somehow attributes
}

module "nuxt-app-slot" {
  source = "./nuxt-app-slot"

  //skip this resource for non-dev environments
  count = local.prod_only

  name             = "preview"
  app_service_name = "appweb-${var.env}-001"
  
  ...add somehow attributes
}
```

Comment: You can set default values for some of the input variables, but if not, I'm not sure if there is a better way. Unless you manage to come to a solution where you have one module and then use `for_each` for example.

Comment: DRY isn't Terraform priority: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5480.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can edit all the modules you're using, you can abstract common properties into a "context object" like so

```
locals {
 context = {
  env              = var.env
  location         = var.location
  tags             = local.tags
  rg_name          = var.rg_name
  subscription_id  = var.subscription_id
  service_plan_id  = local.service_plan_id
  nodejs_version   = var.nodejs_version
 }
}

// development front-end NUXT APP dev
module "nuxt-app" {
  source = "./nuxt-app"

  context          = local.context
  name             = "appweb-${var.env}-001"
  app_service_name = "appweb-${var.env}-001"
}

module "nuxt-app-slot" {
  source = "./nuxt-app-slot"

  //skip this resource for non-dev environments
  count = local.prod_only

  context          = local.context
  name             = "preview"
  app_service_name = "appweb-${var.env}-001"
}
```

You can declare the variable on your modules like so

```
variable "context" {
  type = (object({
    env        = string,
    location   = string,
    ...
  }))

}

variable "billing_users" {
  description = "The list of users identified by their UPN that shall be granted billing access"
  type = list(object({
    email = string,
    upn   = string,
  }))
}
```

An alternative you could wish for is a spread operator, which is unfortunately not in terraform as of today, see e.g. [Spread operator at terraform files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64446260/spread-operator-at-terraform-files)

Comment: I understand, it's already an improvement to what I have.  Thank you!

Comment: Won't it add a new context field to the module instead of adding all context values at the root level of the module?